# Cannot run or uninstall Firefox after automatic update

Tags: windows-7, firefox

- I don't use Firefox much (couple of times a week)
- Opened it today, it decided to perform an automatic update.
- After the update, when I opened Firefox it just shows a white screen
- I try to kill the process, but the process won't die
- If I restart my machine and try to uninstall, the uninstaller won't progress

Windows 7, 64-bit

How do I correct this?

Comment: @MelissaLoos Why would deleting the folder make any difference? Can you recommend a registry cleaner which can remove only Firefox keys?

Comment: Have you asked Firefox if their latest update has been tested & proven working on WIn7. No-one is really going to be testing against it any more… things will work until they break.

Comment: Firefox is supposed to work on Windows 7. Uninstall it using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/) to clean up disk and registry, then download and install the latest version.

Comment: Running fine here on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 74.0

Comment: Have you tried Firefox safe mode?